# ASP.NET login fails when I move the application folder

Tags: asp.net, authentication, roles

Note that applicationName="/MyApplication" in web.config is the same in both locations. I am using ASPNET Roles. If I create a member in root folder "localhost\MyApplication" and try to login with that username in the 'moved' application "localhost\Test\MayApplication", I can not login with that user name. It does validate the password against the user name and it is correct, it just about permission, I am denied access.

On the other hand if I create a user in localhost\test\MyApplication and try to login with that application in the root application, I can successfuly login.

What am I missing?

Thank you for taking the time to answering my question.

Edit : Code

```
<providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ABC_Connection" applicationName="/MyApplication" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
</providers>
```

Edit 2:
Checked folder permission (the actual folder) and added IUSR, ASPNET but did not work out yet

Comment: can you please give here the web.config of this part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question. The AppName = "" must be provided for the database provide just as your do for application. If you move the application, websever changes the application name based on where the application is. If you provide the application name, that name will not be changed and login issue will be resolved. I may refine this answer but just to provide a quick solution.